# Create command that uses a \foreach to be used in a barycentric cs

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying create a command that will be used in a `barycentric cs:`.

I will use the `barycentric cs` a lot of time to get a node the middle of others, so I'm trying to make it less painfull for myself. It will also be used in another command that uses a list as its parameter.

Let's say I have this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        basic/.style={
            draw, 
            rounded corners=2pt, 
            thick, 
            text width=8em, 
            align=flush center, 
            node distance=2em
        }
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[row sep=2em, column sep=4em, every node/.style={basic}] {
            \node(a){text}; & \node(c){text}; \\
            \node(b){text}; & \node(d){text}; \\
            % Loads of other nodes
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to create a command so that, instead of using `\node (bc#) at (barycentric cs:a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,<...>) {text};`, I only have to write `\node (x) at (baricentric cs:\listforbarycentrics{a,b,c,d}) {text};`.

I tried with this command code:

```
\newcommand{\listforbarycentrics}[1]{\foreach \n in {#1}{
        \n=1,
    };
}
```

However, it doesn't works. It may be because a comma at the end of the list in the `barycentric cs:` (like this`barycentric cs:a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,`) creates an error, however I'm not sure.

Comment: Your strategy works in principle if you do something like `\newcommand{\listforbarycentrics}[1]{\foreach \n [count=\m] in {#1}{
\ifnum\m=1
 \xdef\mybary{\n=1}
\else
\xdef\mybary{\mybary,\n=1}
\fi}}
\listforbarycentrics{a,b,c,d}
\node (x) at (barycentric cs:\mybary) {text};` but I would use a style for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        basic/.style={
            draw, 
            rounded corners=2pt, 
            thick, 
            text width=8em, 
            align=flush center, 
            node distance=2em
        },
        barycentric setup/.code={\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#1}
        {\ifnum\Y=1
         \xdef\baryarg{\X=1}
        \else
         \xdef\baryarg{\baryarg,\X=1}
        \fi}},
        barycentric list/.style={barycentric setup={#1},insert path={%
        (barycentric cs:\baryarg)}}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[row sep=2em, column sep=4em, every node/.style={basic}] {
            \node(a){text}; & \node(c){text}; \\
            \node(b){text}; & \node(d){text}; \\
            % Loads of other nodes
        };
        \path[barycentric list={a,b,c,d}] node {center}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]